# How to OWASP ZAP scan external REST API using OAuth2

Tags: rest-api, isv, security-review, chimera-security-scanner, zap-scanner

I have built a `Managed Package` that talks to an `external REST API` using `OAuth2 Named Credentials`. I now want to submit this app for `Security Review`. I can't use the `Chimera Scanner` as it would require someone to place this Abuse Token at the root of the endpoint server. I can't do that.
So I try to make it work with OWASP ZAP instead but I couldn't find an understandable tutorial on how to make that work in ZAP.

I have no clue on how to put that into ZAP to finally and successfully click on "Attack".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> For Finding vulnerabilities in the API only application(does not have a web app and you have access to only its REST API), you can configure [proxies in the Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/proxy/) and execute OAuth and other REST api invocations and network requests goes through same proxy that ZAP is configured to intercept.

> If You have web app you can configure your browser as proxy so that any URL you browse through goes through a proxy server which ZAP can intercept.

**Steps**

> Generate a ***root certificate***  in zap to import into the browser/Postman(if you are testing an api). Go to **Tools > Options > Dynamic SSL Certificates** and save this locally.

[image]

> Import the certificate to the browser/Postman(I suggest you use another browser solely for this than one you currently use for general purpose. Makes it easier that you do not mess with your current config. I usually prefer Mozilla for this as i use chrome for general purpose)

For firefox go to `about:preferences` url and select Privacy and Security and choose certificates

Go to Authorities to import the certificate you have saved in step 1

[image]

If you are testing for api only and does not have a web app and you use ***Postman*** to make a request , save your certificate in Postman using preferences tab as shown below

[image]

- Configure your browser proxy url as shown below. You can go to Network Settings in your browser to do this using `about:preferences`.

[image]

- Configure the Local Proxy in ZAP tool using **Tools > Options > Local Proxy**

[image]

Now any URL you browse will be recorded with complete hierarchy. This appears under the Sites as shown here

[image]

If your app is an API only then configure proxy in Postman.

Use [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to make request and it will record the URL for the attack. For OAuth 2.0 go through the Authentication using the Postman configuration.

One important thing to verify here is to make sure Postman uses a same proxy as that of the zap tool.

You can configure in preferences as explained in below article

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/proxy/

[image]

If you further need to customize one can use authentication scripts in ZAP (You generally do not need this until you have a complex authentication or want to test with specific headers) and ZAP has community scripts that covers some sample use cases and scripts [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts)

> Finally to scan or Spider attack the URL all you need to do is right
> click and execute the Attack as shown in below image

[image]

> Use the reports tab to generate the ZAP Report that you can submit to Sec review team.

[image]

**Additional Resources**

ZAP configuration tutorial from salesforce security help is [here](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/webapp/zapbrowsersetup) and steps to configure documented is [here](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/webapp/zapbrowsersetup)

Note that ZAP is free and flexible and to customize you can read the [docs](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/?shell#introduction)

Also ZAP has video tutorials [here](https://www.alldaydevops.com/zap-in-ten)

Comment: Your answer only covers the scanning of browsable web apps using a browser proxy. That's not what I want. I need to scan an OAuth2 secured REST API endpoint. 

Comment: Please use postman as mentioned there to execute your rest call and it will all be recorded and then you can attack. I have adopted this technique in the past and it works! Also i have mentioned if it gets complex you have to script it as per the need!

Comment: I updated once more step there is to make sure postman makes request through same proxy as that of the zap tool.

Comment: It worked and I will make yours the selected answer but I kindly ask you to remove the irrelevant information. Instead of showing how to proxy firefox show all the steps needed to Set Certificare and Proxy inside Postman. Then the answer is helpful to others.

Comment: I think it’s ok to keep and enhance it. I will work on it once I am on the computer to refine it better! The answer can be general purpose here!

Comment: I'd prefer to keep it shorter and just answer for API scans as this was my question about. For me such an answer would be to bloated and detailed. Maybe we can also remove Screen shots where they are not needed and just have a numbered step list linking the salesforce tutorial. I can also create an own answer if you dont want. ;-)

Comment: @robert feel free to share and accept your own answer:) I am off the computer for sometime! Glad I was able to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110175/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-robert-sosemann).

Comment: Great instruction, thank you!
I would note that the certificate you’re adding in Postman is a CA one. The original screenshot seemed a bit misleading to me.

Answer (score 4):

If the accepted answer is too detailed for you, here is a short summary of what was important for me:

- ZAP is the right tool. But forget everything you read on Google on how to make it directly talk to OAuth REST. **Use a Proxy through Postman** instead.
- What works with Web App Proxies ([described in detailed here](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/webapp/zapbrowsersetup)) also works with [Postman Proxies described here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/proxy/).

**Steps I have taken:**

1. Create and save self-signed Certificate from ZAP
2. Add Certificate to Postman
3. Set Postman to go through localhost Proxy
4. Turn off Postman setting to not use Self-signed certificates
5. Create or Import a Postman collection for the external API
6. OAuth-authenticate (or any other mechanism) from Postman
7. ZAP should now record all those calls
8. In ZAP run a Spider scan on API root endpoint
9. Save HTML Report in ZAP and check for issues.